# Windows 10 unhide taskbar with hotkey instead of cursor position

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, taskbar, hotkeys

As the title suggests, I would like to know what registry entries and files I would have to edit to do this. The problem is, I like my taskbar on the left, and hidden to maximize the space used by a window. This is an issue, however, because with how windows 10 captures the mouse within windows, my cursor will still unhide the taskbar, and then my mouse escapes the window that is attempting to capture it. The only solution to this that I can see would be to edit the hitbox for the taskbar to unhide to zero pixels, so that there is no way to open it with the mouse. Then the issue would be how to unhide the taskbar at all, the solution then would be to set a global hotkey to unhide it, so what would I have to edit to do this?

Comment: There are no registry entries to modify.  The taskbar is part of the shell.

Comment: @Keltari Care to expand upon this a bit? Would it be possible by any reasonable means to edit the shell?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that I was able to find is to use a program called Taskbar Control. It's certainly not exactly what I wanted and is not elegant by any means since I still have to have the taskbar on auto hide, and when I want to stop my mouse from opening it, toggle the hotkey. I've also heard that you can use Auto HotKey to do it too, and I will put the code for that below, but I do not have any experience with that. I just used the TBC program, which works. It's a stop-gap solution that sucks, but that's what is out there.

Auto hotkey code that binds the hide/unhide hotkey to win+h:

```
    LWin & h::
    if toggle := !toggle {
        WinHide ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
        WinHide Start ahk_class Button
    }
    else {
        WinShow ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
        WinShow Start ahk_class Button
    }
    return
```

Comment: the problem is that this auto hot key script disables windows+number to select apps in your taskbar

Comment: maybe this https://github.com/LuisThiamNye/ButteryTaskbar2

Answer (score 0):

**<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>** is the built-in global HotKey for unhiding a hidden Taskbar.

Comment: This doesn't work on my system windows 10 2004